# Cheap camera to record minimum 4 hours video with tiemstamp on video

Tags: video-camera

As the title says. I have a single use need for a video camera, hence "cheap". I have only two requirements:

1. mumst be able to record a minimum of 4 hours in a single video
2. the camera must record a timestamp onto the video

I currently have access to a Go-Pro Hero7, but it looks like the timestamp has to be added in post-processing by using some additional software. This is sub-optimal.

Note that there is no need for GPS, which should keep the price down.

---

[Update] minimum 720 fps

Comment: have you considered a point-and-shoot digital camera with a high capacity memory card? I have a Canon that can be equipped with a battery eliminator to handle the duration and it will time-stamp the video. The model I have may be limited by card size but now sells for US$30 on eBay. Other models may be better suited for larger cards.

Comment: Sounds good! Feel free to post an answer, but, ***please*** tell me what model you have?

Comment: I've just shot myself in the foot. My canon powershot sx200 IS does time and date stamps but only in still mode. My defective alleged memory recalls viewing a "movie" I created that contained the timestamp but it was composed of individual still shots taken with the CHDK (Canon Hack Development Kit) turned into a GIF. There may be point-and-shoot cameras but my model isn't one of them. The CHDK has a scripted intervalometer, making time-lapse easy (and free).

Comment: I have found a Python script to add timestamps afterwards. It needs some work, but I am a programmer. Problem is that a friend has asked for help & his idea of "mates' rates" is "free". I am overloaded, so the simplest solution for me is a camera that can do it :-)